# extract SNMP raw trap from PCAP file using wireshark

Tags: unix, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I have a `.PCAP` file which has tcpdump data, now when i open using wireshark it shows source and destination address and all OID's but can i add MIB's in wireshark and extract exact raw SNMP trap from it with all fields?

If yes then please tell me steps as i have MIB, Wireshark and pcap file all.